# Calculate age between two integer columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, datetime

I have the below df:

```
OnlineDate    BDate
20190813      19720116
20190809      19570912
20190807      19600601
20190801      19760919
20190816      19530916
```

The two columns are integer and are dates YYYYMMDD

I'm trying to get a new column that is the result in Years between these two dates.

So, the expected output is the next

```
OnlineDate    BDate       NewColumn
20190813      19720116       47
20190809      19570912       61
20190807      19600601       59
20190801      19760919       51
20190816      19530916       66
```

I can't just subtract the years because the days and months count to determine the year,

Do I have to create a function to do it or I can do it without one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It requires some setup, but you're looking to convert your columns to a datetime, get the year from it and then simply subtract them to get the differences

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# setup
onlinedate = [20190813, 20190809, 20190807, 20190801, 20190816]
bdate = [19720116, 19570912, 19600601, 19760919, 19530916]

df = pd.DataFrame({"onlinedate":onlinedate, "bdate":bdate})

# convert to dates
onlinedate_year = pd.to_datetime(df["onlinedate"], format="%Y%M%d")
bdate_year = pd.to_datetime(df["bdate"], format="%Y%M%d")
# Setup new column, columnwise operation
# Subtract the two dates and divide by years
df["NewColumn"] = ((onlinedate_year - bdate_year)/np.timedelta64(1,'Y'))
# convert the float column in to int
df["NewColumn"] = df["NewColumn"].astype(int)


print(df)
```

output:

```
   onlinedate     bdate  NewColumn
0    20190813  19720116         46
1    20190809  19570912         61
2    20190807  19600601         59
3    20190801  19760919         42
4    20190816  19530916         65
```

Comment: But if you take the first raw  in your output the result is wrong it must be 46 and not 47, that's  why I have to take the month and day to create the new column

Comment: @Jozamvg I misread your ask, please see see the update.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the data types to datetime;

```
for col in ['OnlineDate','BDate']:
    df[col]=pd.to_datetime(df[col],format="%Y%m%d")
```

Subtract the years;

```
df['NewColumn']=df['OnlineDate'].dt.year-df['BDate'].dt.year
```